# 404 specific image error for a directory (symlink)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I am trying to serve a specific jpeg picture that depends on the directory.

For example:

- /i/t/150/63211.jpg => /i/404/150.jpg
- /i/t/195/63211.jpg =>/i/404/195.jpg

At the moment, even something simple (one rule at a time) like :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/i/t/150/.*\.jpg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /i/404/150.jpg  [L]
```

Doesn't work even if my jpeg file is in the directory /i/404/.

**I think the problem comes from the fact that /i/ is a symlink.**

My goal is to have the 2 rules (for 150.jpg/195.jpg) in the same RewriteRule. But let's try to make it work with one only.

Here is my full htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)-a([0-9]+)\.html$ 301oldninapeople.php?oldid=$2&section=news [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-n([0-9]+)\.html$ 301oldninapeople.php?oldid=$2&section=theme [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-n([0-9]+)-page([0-9]+)\.htm$ 301oldninapeople.php?oldid=$2&section=theme [L]

RewriteRule ^301oldninapeople\.php$ - [PT,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/i/t/150/.*\.jpg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /i/404/150.jpg  [L]



RedirectMatch 301 ^/rss/news.(xml|asp)$ /feed

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Current robots.txt after the first answer:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^i/t/([^/]+)/.+?\.jpg$ /i/404/$1.jpg [L,NC,R]

RewriteRule ^(.*)-a([0-9]+)\.html$ 301oldninapeople.php?oldid=$2&section=news [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-n([0-9]+)\.html$ 301oldninapeople.php?oldid=$2&section=theme [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-n([0-9]+)-page([0-9]+)\.htm$ 301oldninapeople.php?oldid=$2&section=theme [L]

RewriteRule ^301oldninapeople\.php$ - [PT,L]




RedirectMatch 301 ^/rss/news.(xml|asp)$ /feed
# RedirectMatch 301 ^/rss/news.xml$ /feed
# RedirectMatch 301 ^/rss/news.asp$ /feed

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0 -f
RewriteRule ^i/t/([^/]+)/.+?\.jpg$ /i/404/$1.jpg [L,NC]
```

Also make sure to move this rule as **first rule** just below `RewriteBase /` line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I add this rule, I have an error 500 :( Also, I want this rule to be executed only if there is a 404.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo that is fixed and I added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` for 404 handling.

Comment: I have added your rule at the top but I still have a 404 when I try to load this file: /i/t/150/64791.jpg instead of having /i/404/150.jpg :(

Comment: I still have a 404 with that answer :s Thanks for your time again.

Comment: That could be due to WP rules. Try adding R as: `RewriteRule ^i/t/([^/]+)/.+?\.jpg$ /i/404/$1.jpg [L,NC,R]`

Comment: Do you hanged URI in browser now? => I don't get the question?

Comment: Sorry I was typing on mobile. Question was: `Do you get changed URI  /i/404/150.jpg in browser now?`

Comment: Yes, when I go to http://www.mywebsite.com/i/404/150.jpg, it works. But if I go to www.mywebsite.com/i/t/150/000000.jpg I have a 404 :(

Comment: With `R` flag `/i/t/150/000000.jpg` for me redirects to `/i/404/150.jpg` Are you sure this rule is first rule in your .htaccess

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess in `/i/` or in `/i/t/` or in `/i/t/150/`?

Comment: no, but the the think that I should have said is that /i/ is a symbolic link

Comment: Oh i didn't know that. Try adding this line `Options +FollowSymLinks` as the first line in your .htaccess. Also let me know if `/i/t/150/000000.jpg` is being server by WP or not?

Comment: Done but it doesn't work. I have searched online and they say that I could use RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l but it does not work either. 404 is not served by wordpress. Thank you.

Comment: I have made an edit but it is most likely to handle it via your custom theme since WP hijacks this 404

Comment: Still doesn't work. Strange. Anyway, thanks again for your help.

Comment: It will be easy to blame WP but `R` flag will **always cause URL to change in browser**. So it is definitely due to your local issues which unfortunately I cannot predict due to very limited info I have in my hand.